# Find the nearest element with given element in list without using array

Tags: java

I have a program to get the last value before given value. I write it like that:

```
while (rs.next()) {
                int temp = rs.getInt("alarmType");
                double fuel = rs.getDouble("nhienLieu");
                if(temp != 60 ){
                    alarmType = temp;
                        double currentValue = rs.getDouble("fuelLevel");
                        double changeValue = lastValue == 0 ? 0 : currentValue + fuel - lastValue;
                        lastValue = currentValue;
                        reportFuel = new FuelData(
                                rs.getString("accountID"),
                                rs.getString("deviceID"), 
                                rs.getInt("timestamp"),
                                rs.getDouble("latitude"),
                                rs.getDouble("longitude"), 
                                rs.getString("address"),
                                currentValue,
                                rs.getDouble("odometerKM"),
                                rs.getInt("status"),
                                changeValue,
                                alarmType,
                                rs.getDouble("nhienLieu"));
                        list.add(reportFuel);
                        if(fuel > 0){
                            changeValue = fuel;
                    }
                }
            }
```

In this code, I use temporary variable `temp` to assign to value of alarmType, and then I check if `temp` not equal 60 I print the value before it(temp = 60)(only one value nearest). However, my code seem to print all value that satisfy this condition. So how can I do to get only one value nearest `temp = 60` without using array?

Comment: "and then I check if temp equal 60" BUT your code says `temp != 60`

Comment: Can you give us an example, like a short list of four or five records, and which one you think this should return?

Comment: for example: with this list: `1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2` if we suppose temp != 60 correspond with temp != 2 and then I should print out 1, 3 and 3 (before 2). That is the goal which I expected to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this will help you:

```
FuelData tempFD = null;
while(rs.next()){
  int temp = rs.getInt("alarmType");

  if(temp == 60 ){
     //print or add to list tempFD
     tempFD = null; 
  } else {
     tempFD = new FuelData();
  }

}
```

Comment: I think `else {
     tempFD = new FuelData();
  }` still do not show the nearest value temp == 60 but show all the values which different to 60.

Comment: tempFD will always hold the last data from the resultSet. If the temp == 60 then the last value will be processed. So your process steps (adding items to list) must be in the "if" block. In the "else" block only fetch data to tempFD

Answer (score 1):

here you go
based on the example `1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2`

```
int current = -1, prev = -1;
    int data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2 };

    for (int d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
        current = data[d];

        if (current != 2) {
            prev = current;
        }

        if (current == 2 && prev != -1) {
            System.out.print(prev);
        }
    }// while loop
```

**Output: 1 3 3**

just replace the for loop with `while(rs.next())`

and replace `current = data[d];` with `current = rs.getInt("alarmType");`

finally, replace the 2 with 60